# Violação de integridade não lançada em BD Sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, crud

CRUD em C# não está lançando erro de violação de integridade ao deletar registro dependente em BD SQLite.

```
        query = "DELETE FROM "+ table +
                " WHERE id = '" + id + "';";
        int returnValue = 0;
        try
        {
            conn = new SQLiteConnection(connStr);
            conn.Open();
            cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            returnValue = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                
            conn.Close();                
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("O seguinte erro está impedindo o correto " +
                "funcionamento do aplicativo: \r\n" + e.Message);
        }
```

Quando eu apago um cliente que possui registros dependentes nenhum erro é lançado. No SQLite Studio é possível notar que o Cliente foi excluído mas o registro dependente ainda possui a chave herdada de cliente. Outra observação é que o valor de retorno de ExecuteNonQuery() é sempre 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa habilitar o suporte a verificação de chave estrangeira com o seguinte comando:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

Assim o SQLite vai saber que precisa verificar as chaves estrangeiras. Pode verificar isso no item [2 deste link](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)